# Make Juno realize the newly installed Julia version

Tags: julia

I just upgraded Julia from 1.3.1 to 1.4.2. That worked well. However, when I start Juno it still uses the old Julia version. How can I fix this?

(I'm working on a Windows 10 machine, but I guess answers for other OS' should be helpful as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the path in the Atom package settings of the `julia-client` package (shortcut to get there is `Ctrl+J` followed by `Ctrl+,`):

[image]